# HyperV - Import a virtual machine with more virtual cpus than the host's logical processors

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, cpu, import

I am trying to import a virtual machine that was provided to me by someone, to automate it on our multiple machines (About 400) via powershell with the `import-vm` command. This command generates an error
which, when using the following command, says this (Translated from german):

> The number of processors specified for the virtual computer "My_vm"
> cannot be assigned because it is out of range..

There are indeed 8 processors defined on the virtual machine and since the (400 machines) new host machine has only 4 logical ones, it is not possible to import it like that.

I know that it is possible to set the number of processors of an existent machine with `set-vmprocessor`, but it only works when it is imported. And the error occurs when importing vm, which causes the fact that I can't even access it to change the resources afterwards.

But then my question is this.

How can we change the number of processors before the import? By changing the vmcx file?
Or is the only solution to import the virtual machine manually, change the number of processors and import it again?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yes; The configuration file would indicate how many processors or cores the virtual machine has access to when it's turned on.  Manually creating a copy of that file, modifying it in a text editor, and lowering the number of processors it has assigned would solve your problem. There is a chance the file is binary.  There are [solutions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/plugins/builders/hyperv/vmcx) for that particular problem.

Comment: Thanks. But my vmcx file looks like this with a text editor file "7åëU   vdev006              t    )  èì³ã   device". I know that with the old xml files it used to be more easy to define those resources

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try this solutions. Looks great :)